# How can I get specific information out of a .txt file in java?

Tags: java, file, text

I'm new to Java and I can't find a way to open a text file and tell my computer ok line 1 from 0 to the " " it's the first node, from " " to " " it's the second node and from " " to \n it's the weight.

This is an extract of the said .txt file

> Eskildstrup Maribo 28
>
> Eskildstrup NykøbingF 13
>
> Eskildstrup Vordingborg 25
>
> Haslev Korsør 60
>
> Haslev Køge 24

The point of the program should be to create a graph and then use prim... It shouldn't be too difficult but I'm having a real tough time doing the sorting in the first place...

I have examples of how I did it on C++:

```
while(std::getline(game, s))
        {
            std::string n=s.substr(0,s.find("="));
            if(n==m_nom)
            {
                existe=true;
                std::string m=s.substr(s.find("=")+1,100000000);
                std::string o=m.substr(0, m.find(";"));
                std::string coin=m.substr(m.find(";")+1, 100000000);
                std::cout<< o<<std::endl<<coin<<std::endl;
    
                std::string delimiter = ",";
```

or

```
    for (int i = 0; i < m_ordre; i++)
        {
            int tempId=0;
            std::string tempNom;
            double tempAltitude=0;
    
            ifs >> tempId >> tempNom >> tempAltitude;
            m_stations.push_back(new Sommet(tempId, tempNom, tempAltitude));
        }
```

But I can't seem to be able to do the same in Java.
For now, I have my node, vertices, and graph classes.

This is what my graph class looks like rn...

```
class Graph
{
    public Graph(File doc){
        try {
            BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(doc));
            String s, line, unique, del=" ";
            while ((s= br.readLine())!= null)
                System.out.println(s);
            while () {

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a sample from that file? Your description is ok, but an example would be a lot better (copy, paste, try for readers that want to answer).

Comment: Of course! I completely forgot to do so!

Comment: Looks like you already found how to read the file line by line. If you're simply looking  how to split the string into parts, use the `String#split` method which returns you an array of all the parts

Comment: First of all, I recommend the use of `java.nio`, you can get a `List<String> lines` with the lines of the file and since each line seems to represent a single edge in your graph, it would be a good start. Do you know `java.nio`? And yes, `split` each line by `"\\s+"` or similar to get the values that are separated with whitespace(s) per line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very basic approach, but might be sufficient:

1. read the lines of the file
2. split each line by whitespace(s)
3. handle the results (for instance, create an edge for your graph)

The following example uses `java.nio.Path` and `java.nio.Files` for the operations 1. and 2. mentioned above:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileLocation = "/path/to/your/graph-coords.txt";
    // create a Path from the String
    Path filePath = Paths.get(fileLocation);
    // if everything is fine with the file (checks omitted for brevity), read its lines
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(filePath);
    // then handle each line:
    lines.forEach(line -> {
        // split each line by an arbitrary number of whitespaces
        String[] lineValues = line.split("\\s+");
        // and do what you want with the results, e.g. create an edge of the graph
        System.out.println(lineValues[0] + " --" + lineValues[2] + "km--> " + lineValues[1]);
    });
}
```

The output of this code is

```
Eskildstrup --28km--> Maribo
Eskildstrup --13km--> NykøbingF
Eskildstrup --25km--> Vordingborg
Haslev --60km--> Korsør
Haslev --24km--> Køge
```

As an example of handling the values, I just rearranged them into a different `String` assuming the *weight* is a distance in kilometers. Having all the lines of the file in a `Collection` makes checking for linebreaks obsolete (a really handy thing of this library).

Create the initial `String` with respect to the system of your computer, I used a Linux/MacOs style path, on Windows, you will have to provide a drive letter, I think.

This answer only shows how to read the lines and split them into single values. It does not check for existence of or read access to the file, though possible with `java.nio` (e.g. `java.nio.Files.isRegularFile(Path filePath)` or `java.nio.Files.isReadable(Path filePath)` and `java.nio.Files.exists(Path filePath)`). `Exception` handling is mandatory, here I just made the `main` method `throw` an `IOException` to get the code compiled.

Comment: thank you so much I'm gonna look into it right away